# What is the propellant tank weight or weight ratio on dry weight of liquid propellant rocket engine?

Tags: rockets, engines, design, engineering, ares-v

I need propellant tank ( or oxidizer tank)'s dry weight- without propellant and engine mass. For example ARES-V's dry mass at earth departure stage is 21,795 kg, What percent of this is tanks' dry weight?

Is there any formula to calculate this?

Comment: Posting as a comment because I don't think it meets your criterion of a "formula", but there's a paper about how to do it here `Estimation of Launch Vehicle Propellant Tank Structural
Weight Using Simplified Beam Approximation` https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/8381/2004JPCprintversion.pdf and another one here `Analysis of Propellant Tank Masses` https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/382034main_018%20-%2020090706.05.Analysis_of_Propellant_Tank_Masses.pdf

Comment: It also depends on what you want included in the "tank", what about the structural elements required for supporting the whole rockets mass on the ground and during pressurization and acceleration? the tank usually has to be thicker to accommodate this as the tank skin is the one and only skin of the rocket (except for bulkheads).

Comment: @Slarty And sometimes rather odd things are done to reduce this. The larger Atlas V fairings attach to the first stage, enclosing the entire second stage along with the payload, so the second stage doesn't have to handle aerodynamic forces in addition to the payload. The LOX tank of the Delta IV upper stage dangles from the larger-diameter LH2 tank which is supported by the interstage, only the LH2 tank supports the payload above it when the vehicle's on the pad or in the first stage burn.

Comment: Also, mass on earlier stages doesn't have as big an impact on payload as mass on later stages, since that mass doesn't get carried all the way to orbit. The forces the tanks are exposed to and the costs and benefits of optimizing their masses depend on the exact situation, it's not something that you'll get a simple formula for.